# Speed up Index/Match in Excel Formula for 65,000 queries

Tags: excel, vba, performance

I'm attempting to run an index/match query for 65,000 cells as part of a store inventory calculation in Excel. We have 65,000 unique items in our database.

Anyways, here is the formula I am pasting down a single column for 65,000 rows. Obviously, it runs EXTREMELY slow. What could I possibly change to speed things up?

```
=INDEX(SAQTY!H:H, MATCH(A2&"GRA", SAQTY!C:C&SAQTY!F:F, 0))
```

On a side note, the index/match is cross checking across multiple sheets, does that have anything to do with performance?

Comment: Do you need to use the full column references?

Comment: You need to limit the references to only those cells with data.  Change all the full column references to limited references.  Right now each formula is doing over 2 million calculations.  2 million * 65000 = 130,000,000,000 calculations.

Comment: No, but the range does need to include all available values in the SAQTY sheet. In VBA I know how to specify the "last cell with data", but I have no idea how to do it in an excel cell formula

Comment: Does it need to be dynamic? Perhaps 100,000 rows would always do the trick?

Comment: That's definitely the problem then. As the column count is changing on a daily basis for the source data, how would I change the formula to find the last cell wtih data?

Comment: It doesn't necessairly need to be dynamic @CallumDA, but I would like to future proof it if possible.

Comment: Are columns H:H,C:C,F:F text or numbers?

Comment: Do a quick search on dynamic named ranges. They often use the `OFFSET` and `COUNTA` functions to dynamically resize your named range

Comment: @ScottCraner numbers

Comment: @CallumDA OFFSET being volatile will have a negative effect on the calc times.  INDEX/MATCH is not volatile.

Comment: Good point. Your answer covers it nicely

Comment: `Match` performs much better if your lookup array is sorted and the Match_Type parameter is set to 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make the references dynamic like this:

```
=INDEX(SAQTY!H:H, MATCH(A2&"GRA", SAQTY!C1:INDEX(SAQTY!C:C,MATCH(1E+99,SAQTY!H:H))&SAQTY!F1:INDEX(SAQTY!F:F,MATCH(1E+99,SAQTY!H:H)), 0))
```

Comment: I was just writing something similar but relied on dynamic named ranges (defined with similar formulas). However, it isn't necessary to dynamically define `SAQTY!H:H`. It can be left as a full column reference with no ill effect.

Comment: @Jeeped are you saying that the full column reference, is in fact, dynamic?

Comment: @AlexRitter - Dynamic ranges are only necessary for the concatenated ranges in the [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca); not in the `SAQTY!H:H`. No speed difference using `(SAQTY!H:H`.

Comment: @Jeeped oh ok I follow.

Comment: @Jeeped unless the match ranges start on a different row than 1.  But yes, I have found that true too.

Comment: @Scrott Craner Thanks for this solution man. My calculation is currently at 15%, a SIGNIFICANT performance boost.

Comment: @ScottCraner I have found that this solution only works for cells with numerical lookup values, is there a solution for lookup values containing text?

Comment: @AlexRitter that is why I asked, and you stated Numeric.  Change the `1E+99` to `"ZZZ"`

Comment: @ScottCraner You did ask, and I'm sorry I didn't specify both. Thanks!